# Stream/Infinite Stream interface definition

Tags: c#, class

What I want do is the following:

```
public interface IRemove<out T>
{
    T Remove();
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
}

public interface IRemoveInfinite<out T> : IRemove<T>
{
    bool IsCompleted { get { return false; } } 
}
```

But this isn't valid, as I can't put implementations in C# interfaces.

Given the following constraints:

1. Every `IRemoveInfinite` is also an `IRemove` automatically.
2. Ensure there is no way to successfully compile an `IRemoveInfinite` which has `IsCompleted` ever set to false when treated as an `IRemove`.
3. Allow these interfaces to be implemented on classes which already have parents.
4. I want to be able to enforce receiving an infinite stream at compile, some functions might require infinite streams if they don't have a way to deal with them being finished.

How can I code up such interfaces or otherwise encapsulating this?

Answer (score 2):

Interface is a declaration of contract, but you try to insert implementation of this contract into it.

Maybe you should use abstract class to define behavior:

```
public interface IRemove<out T>
{
    T Remove();

    bool IsCompleted { get; }
}

public abstract class RemoveInfinite<T> : IRemove<T>
{
    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public abstract T Remove();
}
```

If you can't use inheritance, use composition of classes:

```
public class ClassRemove : RemoveInfinite<object>
{
    public override object Remove()
    {
        return new object();
    }
}

public class ClassA : SomeBaseClass, IRemove<object>
{
    private RemoveInfinite<object> removeInfinite = new ClassRemove();

    public object Remove()
    {
        return removeInfinite.Remove();
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return removeInfinite.IsCompleted; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And for fun (and I think it looks nicer!) `public bool IsCompleted => false;`

Comment: @DavidG yes, but it depends on C# version